# Different datepickers for different devices

Tags: css, asp.net, angularjs, html

I am making a website with angular that contains datepickers. How can I get windows datepicker when the website is opened on a windows pc, and get a android datepicker when the website is opened with an android?

Answer (score 1):

simply use `<input type='date'/>` , this will let you select date from default datepicker the mobile platform natively uses. i.e. android will use its own, while windows will use its own  native one

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Date Picker Format:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

SCRIPT :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```